# Sending a large image using base64 to nginx+uwsig+django server

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm using `base64` to upload an image to a Django server. When the image size is larger than 2M, the server can't get the image.

I set up the `uwsgi` and `nginx` configuration, and made the upload size 75M, but it did not work.

Client:

```py
image1 = base64.b64encode(open(file_path, 'rb').read())
r = requests.post(url, data={"image": image1})
```

Server:

```py
result = request.POST.get("image")
```

````
Nginx:

```bash
server {
# the port your site will be served on
listen     ****;
# the domain name it will serve for
#server_name .example.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
server_name ****;
charset utf-8;

# max upload size
client_max_body_size 75M;
}
```
uwsgi:

```bash
# ocr.ini file
# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir= /root/ubuntu
# Django's wsgi file
module= mysite.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home= /root/ubuntu
# process-related settings
# master
master= true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes= 32
max-requests= 10000
daemonize= /tmp/a.log
pidfile= /tmp/a.pid
#reload-on-as = 126
#reload-on-rss = 126
#enable-threads= true
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket= /root/ubuntu/mysite.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket= 666
# clear environment on exit
vacuum= true
limit-post= 20000000

harakiri=30
post-buffering=20000000
py-autoreload = 1
```
````

Error:

[image: 1]

Comment: Could you please update your question with your nginx configuration and any other relevant code you have? This will help us understand the problem better. Thanks!

Comment: any errors that are output in a terminal or log file would help a great deal aswell

Answer (score 0):

You're probably hitting a hard limit set somewhere in the server's library. If you are trying to upload such a big file, then using a POST passing everything in a `data` parameter is a bad idea (and also really slow).

You should use the `files` keyword argument for sending with `requests`, and the `FILES` property for receiving with Django.

Client:

```
r = requests.post(files={'image': open(file_path,'rb')})
```

Server:

```
img = request.FILES.get("xxx") # <-- file name here

with open('path/to/destination', 'wb') as dest:
    for chunk in img.chunks():
        dest.write(chunk)
```

Check out the [File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/file-uploads/) page on the Django documentetion.